# Appcelerator Titanium: Download and interpret JavaScript code at runtime?

Tags: javascript, download, runtime, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I have a simple question and can not find an answer.
Can JavaScript code for Titanium be downloaded and interpreted as native app at runtime?
Or must the code be compiled within the application?

Best regards

Comment: Depending on what you are trying to do, there shouldn't be anything wrong with pre-building in functionality you know you'll need and some sort of configuration file that activates those functions.  For example, sending a JSON configuration file that dynamically generates an input screen that didn't exist should be okay.  The execution code existed at the time the app was evaluated.  You aren't sending new execution code, you are just configuring your app based on input from a data source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In theory, Javascript CAN be downloaded and used. That is also basically how liveview/TiShadow works. However, officially you're not allowed to do this by Apple. Not sure what the Android policy is.

So if your goal is to update the app remotely, yes you CAN, but you're not allowed AND I do not recommend it. How will you properly keep track of versions, and how to deal with a introduced bug that breaks the app, thus the app not being able to update remotely.

Just don't do it!

Comment: Thank you. Also, the information this is not allowed by Apple is new for me. Can you post the uri of this information?

Comment: Rene is correct. There is a requirement wherein it states that (Apple developer or application) should not download executable codes from remote server. That would a violation of the guidelines.